# merging text file and mp3 file with serialization in c#/xaml metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, serialization, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing a note taking app, in which user will record the audio and will do some text inputting. At the end I will have one .txt file and another .mp3 file. Now I want to merge this two files in one single file. Further I will also need to separate both the file when user open that single file. So what should I do ? Should I use XML serialization as there is no binary serialization in WinRT ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, some options include:

1. Use a zip file (or some other container)
2. Encode the mp3 in Base 64 and send it as a string (XML would work well here)
3. Put the text in one of the mp3 header tags
4. Create a new file format which includes both mp3 data and text data
5. Use multi-part MIME, like an email does when sending attachments

Comment: zip => I can do with System.IO.Compression | Encoding in Base64 => It doesn't seem feasible as 986 KB MP3 require 1.28 MB text of Base64 | MP3 header tags => I don't know I to edit MP3 headers, may be not available in WinRT | New file format => How can I do this ? | Multi part MIME => How can I do this ?